# lean prover for $\neg (p \wedge \neg p)$

Tags: theorem-provers

I did this code :

```
section
  variable p : Prop

  example : ¬ (p ∧ ¬ p) :=
    assume h : p ∧ ¬ p,
      show false, from  (and.left h) (and.right h) 
end
```

But I have the following message error :

```
function expected at
  h.left
term has type
  p
```

But, in the other hand,

```
section
  variable A : Prop
  variable h1 : ¬ A
  variable h2 : A

  example : false := h1 h2
end
```

works fine...

How can I eliminate the "not" operator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lean, `¬ p` is just shorthand for `p -> false`.

Therefore, if we have `h1 : ¬ p` and `h2 : p`, then `h1` is a function `h1 : p -> false`. Therefore, `h1 h2 : false`. This is why the example works.

In your example, we have `(and.left h) : p` while `(and.right h) : ¬ p`. The expression `(and.left h) (and.right h)` means "Apply the function `(and.left h` to the value `(and.right h)`". But there's no reason based on the types to think that `(and.left h)` is a function.

The correct way to prove it is, of course, to exhibit an element of type `false` through the expression `(and.right h) (and.left h)`. This is because `and.right h : p -> false` and `and.left h : p`.